# Trying pip download with platform manylinux1_x86_64 still gives error for windows

Tags: python, pip

I have a web server (debian) that is not connected to the internet and would like to run my code in it. I have the code running in my local machine (windows) and also have it running on a dev server that has internet access to it (debian)

To do that I want to

- download all needed pip libraries in my local machine, which is a windows machine
- Upload this libraries to the webserver, which is a debian machine

In my local machine, I created a venv
`python -m venv .venv`

and I extracted all the needed libraries using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` from the dev server (to have same library versions that would work with debian)

From my windows machine, and through the venv, I ran this command

```
pip download --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --no-deps --python-version 311  -r requirements.txt
```

That seems to be downloading for most of the libraries until I encountered this error when downloading uvloop library:

```
Collecting uvloop
  Using cached uvloop-0.19.0.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\**\Downloads\requirements\backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\**\Downloads\requirements\backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\**\Downloads\requirements\backend\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u9ekvm49\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u9ekvm49\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u9ekvm49\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
      RuntimeError: uvloop does not support Windows at the moment
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

does that mean that the --platform option is ignored? shouldn't it be downloading a version that works with linux?

I also noticed in 2 other libraries that it cannot find any version for them which doesn't make sense because they are already installed in the other dev machine. The libraries are:

- onnxruntime
- pulsar-client

Comment: uvloop 0.19.0 only has more recent manylinux platform tags such as `manylinux_2_17_x86_64` or `manylinux2014_x86_64`

Comment: but even if it doesn't have the tag I specified, shouldn't the error be that no version is found? I am worried that the libraries I am downloading are not using the --platform option I specified

Comment: no -- if there's no matching _wheel_ it will try and download a source distribution and run the build to determine the dependencies

Comment: you can specify `--only-binary :all:` and it will not attempt source distributions

Comment: `pip download` for a different platform doesn't really work. Run a virtual machine or a container with the destination platform (processor, OS, Python version).